# problem changing from WebsocketConsumer to AsyncWebsocketConsumer

Tags: django, django-channels

i'm making a chat app with django,
everything is fine and working with the WebsocketConsumer and async_to_sync, but when i change to the AsyncWebSocket i get an error :

```
django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.
```

any idea or suggestion on why is that happening or what i can do here ? thanks for your help.

this is my consumers.py

```
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer

#from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync

from django.utils import timezone

from .models import Message

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from courses.models import Course


class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):

async def connect(self):
        self.user = self.scope['user']
        self.id = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['course_id']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.id
        # join room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            
                    self.room_group_name,
                    self.channel_name)
        # accept connection
        await self.accept()
async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # leave room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
                    self.room_group_name,
                    self.channel_name)
    # receive message from WebSocket
async def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']
        now = timezone.now()
        course = get_object_or_404(Course,id=self.id)
        messages = Message.objects.create(author=self.scope['user'], content=message,course=course)
        # send message to room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
                {
                    'type': 'chat_message',
                    'message': message,
                    'user': self.user.username,
                    'datetime': now.isoformat(),
                }
            )
    # receive message from room group
async def chat_message(self, event):
        # Send message to WebSocket
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps(event))
```

**UPDATE**
I found the **Solution**

those 2 lines are the rcause of the error:

```
course = get_object_or_404(Course,id=self.id)
messages = Message.objects.create(author=self.scope['user'], 
                                  content=message,course=course)
```

i'm using ththem to save messages in the database, aparently it's not possible in the async mode.

so according to the docs this is the modification i added :

```
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async
```

then my save method:

```
    @database_sync_to_async
    def save_message(self,message):
        course = get_object_or_404(Course,id=self.id)
        messages = Message.objects.create(author=self.scope['user'], 
                              content=message,course=course)
        return messages
```

and finally replace the 2 line (the cause of problem) with this line in the receive() method :

```
await self.save_message(message)
```

Comment: Try using `AsyncConsumer` instead of  `AsyncWebsocketConsumer`.

Comment: Also `import asyncio`.

Comment: alright, thank you ,i will try that